# JSON serialize properties on class inheriting list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a model as follows:

```
public class TestResultModel
{
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class TestResultListModel : List<TestResultModel>
{
    public int TotalTestCases { get { return base.Count; } }

    public int TotalSuccessful { get { return base.FindAll(t => t.Successful).Count; } }
}
```

I return this `TestResultListModel` from an `ApiController`:

```
var testResultListModel = new TestResultListModel();
foreach (var testCaseId in new int[] {1,2,3,4})
{
    var testResultModel = new TestResultModel
    {
        Successful = true,
        ErrorMessage = "STRING"
    };

    testResultListModel.Add(testResultModel);
}
return testResultListModel;
```

When I inspect the JSON result it does contain all the `TestResultModel`s, but the properties on the `TestResultListModel` (`TotalTestCases` and `TotalSuccesful`) are not visible.

How can I also include these values in the JSON-serialized object?

What I tried is using `JSON.NET` and decorating the properties with the attribute `[JsonProperty]`, this was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your basic difficulty here is that JSON has two types of container: an object, and an array.  From the [standard](http://json.org/):

- An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
- An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace).

To force a collection's properties to be serialized, mark it with [`[JsonObject]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOverrideIEnumerable.htm):

```
[JsonObject]
public class TestResultListModel : List<TestResultModel>
{
    public int TotalTestCases { get { return base.Count; } }

    public int TotalSuccessful { get { return base.FindAll(t => t.Successful).Count; } }
}
```

Of course, if you do this, **the items will not be serialized**, because a JSON container can have properties, or items -- but not both.  If you want both, you will need to add a synthetic array property to hold the items -- which can be private if you want.

`[JsonObject]` will also cause base class properties such as [`Capacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be serialized, which you likely do not want.  To suppress base class properties, use [`MemberSerialization.OptIn`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm).  Thus your final class should look something like:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class TestResultListModel : List<TestResultModel>
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int TotalTestCases { get { return base.Count; } }

    [JsonProperty]
    // Using Enumerable.Count() is more memory efficient than List.FindAll()
    public int TotalSuccessful { get { return this.Count(t => t.Successful); } }

    [JsonProperty]
    TestResultModel[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                this.AddRange(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives JSON that looks like:

> ```
> {
>   "TotalTestCases": 4,
>   "TotalSuccessful": 2,
>   "Items": [
>     {
>       "Successful": false,
>       "ErrorMessage": "STRING"
>     },
>     {
>       "Successful": true,
>       "ErrorMessage": "STRING"
>     },
>     {
>       "Successful": false,
>       "ErrorMessage": "STRING"
>     },
>     {
>       "Successful": true,
>       "ErrorMessage": "STRING"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

It is possibly more work than it's worth, since these properties could be reconstructed easily on the client side.  (The question [Why not inherit from List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt) suggests avoiding this sort of design.)

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I will reconsider the design. :)