# Newtonsoft Jsonconverter not serializing properties when derived of list<>

Tags: c#, json, inheritance

Consider the code below.
When I try to serialize this by calling the 'SaveToFile' method the property 'Name' doens't get serialized.

Any ideas?

```
public class Subs
{
    public string Something { get; set; } = "smew";
}

public class Plep : List<Subs>
{

    public string Name { get; set; } = "smew";

    public void SaveToFile(string file)
    {

        using (StreamWriter wrt = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            wrt.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                //TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,

            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect it to be serialized to JSON? As array or object with properties? These are incompatible and it seems that Newtonsoft falls back to the List/Array.

Comment: Why do you even **derive** from list? Usually you don´t need this. Instead just **use** a list, e.g. by exposing a `List<Subs>`.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to serialize/deserialize a custom collection with additional properties using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14383736/3744182) and [How do I get json.net to serialize members of a class deriving from `List<T>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21265629/3744182) and [JSON serialize properties on class inheriting list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35439335/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't derive you class from `List<>` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt?rq=1).

Change your class to:

```
public class Plep 
{
public string Name { get; set; } = "smew";
public List<Subs> Subs {get;set;}

public void SaveToFile(string file)
{

    using (StreamWriter wrt = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        wrt.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            //TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,

        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: For now this is the solution i'll be using. It isn't completely what I wanted though, I have to do something else now. I hope to elaborate some more in the near future.