# C# JsonSerializer.Serialize add key value in the generated json

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

I need to group the data in my table by 2 fields to categorize the visualization for the end user, I tried to do it this way, only that the generated json does not contain the key that would be the category name.

My table:

[image]

```
var niveis = _repository.GetAll();

            var queryNestedGroups =
                    (from con in niveis
                    group con by con.Modulo into newGroup1
                    from newGroup2 in
                        (from con in newGroup1
                         group con by con.Submod)
                    group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key).ToList();
```

[image]

the result of

JsonSerializer.Serialize(queryNestedGroups)

```
[
  [
    [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Produtos",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Produtos",
        "Valor": "CAT_PROD_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Produtos",
        "Nome": "Gravar Produtos",
        "Valor": "CAT_PROD_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Produtos",
        "Nome": "Excluir Produtos",
        "Valor": "CAT_PROD_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 4,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Grupos",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Grupos",
        "Valor": "CAT_GRUPO_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 5,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Grupos",
        "Nome": "Gravar Grupos",
        "Valor": "CAT_GRUPO_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 6,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Grupos",
        "Nome": "Excluir Grupos",
        "Valor": "CAT_GRUPO_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 7,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Categorias",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Catagorias",
        "Valor": "CAT_CAT_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 8,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Categorias",
        "Nome": "Gravar Categorias",
        "Valor": "CAT_CAT_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 9,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Categorias",
        "Nome": "Excluir Categorias",
        "Valor": "CAT_CAT_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 10,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Unidades",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Unidades",
        "Valor": "CAT_UNIT_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 11,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Unidades",
        "Nome": "Gravar Unidades",
        "Valor": "CAT_UNIT_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 12,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Unidades",
        "Nome": "Excluir Unidades",
        "Valor": "CAT_UNIT_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 13,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Marcas",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Marcas",
        "Valor": "CAT_MARCA_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 14,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Marcas",
        "Nome": "Gravar Marcas",
        "Valor": "CAT_MARCA_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 15,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Marcas",
        "Nome": "Excluir Marcas",
        "Valor": "CAT_MARCA_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 16,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Atributos",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Atributos",
        "Valor": "CAT_ATTR_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 17,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Atributos",
        "Nome": "Gravar Atributos",
        "Valor": "CAT_ATTR_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 18,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Atributos",
        "Nome": "Excluir Atributos",
        "Valor": "CAT_ATTR_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 19,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Especifica\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Especifica\u00E7\u00E3o",
        "Valor": "CAT_SPEC_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 20,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Especifica\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Nome": "Gravar Especifica\u00E7\u00E3o",
        "Valor": "CAT_SPEC_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 21,
        "IdMod": 1,
        "Modulo": "Catalogo",
        "Submod": "Especifica\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Nome": "Excluir Especifica\u00E7\u00E3o",
        "Valor": "CAT_SPEC_EXCLUI"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "Id": 22,
        "IdMod": 2,
        "Modulo": "Cadastros",
        "Submod": "Fornecedores",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Fornecedor",
        "Valor": "CAD_FORN_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 23,
        "IdMod": 2,
        "Modulo": "Cadastros",
        "Submod": "Fornecedores",
        "Nome": "Gravar Fornecedor",
        "Valor": "CAD_FORN_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 24,
        "IdMod": 2,
        "Modulo": "Cadastros",
        "Submod": "Fornecedores",
        "Nome": "Excluir Fornecedor",
        "Valor": "CAD_FORN_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 25,
        "IdMod": 2,
        "Modulo": "Cadastros",
        "Submod": "Clientes",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Cliente",
        "Valor": "CAD_CLI_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 26,
        "IdMod": 2,
        "Modulo": "Cadastros",
        "Submod": "Clientes",
        "Nome": "Gravar Cliente",
        "Valor": "CAD_CLI_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 27,
        "IdMod": 2,
        "Modulo": "Cadastros",
        "Submod": "Clientes",
        "Nome": "Excluir Cliente",
        "Valor": "CAD_CLI_EXCLUI"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "Id": 28,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Bancos",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Bancos",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_BANCOS_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 29,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Bancos",
        "Nome": "Gravar Bancos",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_BANCOS_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 30,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Bancos",
        "Nome": "Excluir Bancos",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_BANCOS_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 31,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Estados/Cidade",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Estados/Cidade",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_UFCID_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 32,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Estados/Cidade",
        "Nome": "Gravar Estados/Cidade",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_UFCID_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 33,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Estados/Cidade",
        "Nome": "Excluir Estados/Cidade",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_UFCID_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 34,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Condi\u00E7\u00F5es de pagamento",
        "Nome": "Visualizar condi\u00E7\u00E3o de pagamento",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_CONDP_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 35,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Condi\u00E7\u00F5es de pagamento",
        "Nome": "Gravar condi\u00E7\u00E3o de pagamento",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_CONDP_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 36,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Condi\u00E7\u00F5es de pagamento",
        "Nome": "Excluir condi\u00E7\u00E3o de pagamento",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_CONDP_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 37,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Tributa\u00E7\u00E3o CFOP",
        "Nome": "Visualizar CFOP",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CFOP_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 38,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Tributa\u00E7\u00E3o CFOP",
        "Nome": "Gravar  CFOP",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CFOP_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 39,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Tributa\u00E7\u00E3o CFOP",
        "Nome": "Excluir  CFOP",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CFOP_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 40,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST ICMS",
        "Nome": "Visualizar CST ICMS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CSTICMS_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 41,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST ICMS",
        "Nome": "Gravar CST ICMS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CSTICMS_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 42,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST ICMS",
        "Nome": "Excluir CST ICMS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CSTICMS_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 43,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST IPI",
        "Nome": "Visualizar CST IPI",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CSTIPI_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 44,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST IPI",
        "Nome": "Gravar CST IPI",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CSTIPI_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 45,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST IPI",
        "Nome": "Excluir CST IPI",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_CSTIPI_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 46,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST PIS/COFINS",
        "Nome": "Visualizar CST PIS/COFINS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_PISCOFINS_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 47,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST PIS/COFINS",
        "Nome": "Gravar CST PIS/COFINS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_PISCOFINS_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 48,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "CST PIS/COFINS",
        "Nome": "Excluir CST PIS/COFINS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_PISCOFINS_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 49,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "ICMS UF",
        "Nome": "Visualizar ICMS UF",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_ICMSUF_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 50,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "ICMS UF",
        "Nome": "Gravra ICMS UF",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_ICMSUF_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 51,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "ICMS UF",
        "Nome": "Excluir ICMS UF",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_ICMSUF_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 52,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "ORIGENS",
        "Nome": "Visualizar ORIGENS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_ORIGENS_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 53,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "ORIGENS",
        "Nome": "Gravar ORIGENS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_ORIGENS_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 54,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "ORIGENS",
        "Nome": "Excluir ORIGENS",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_ORIGENS_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 55,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "FORMA PAG.",
        "Nome": "Visualizar FORMA PAG.",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_FORMAPAG_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 56,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "FORMA PAG.",
        "Nome": "Gravar FORMA PAG.",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_FORMAPAG_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 57,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "FORMA PAG.",
        "Nome": "Excluir FORMA PAG.",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_FORMAPAG_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 58,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Integra\u00E7\u00E3o Fiscal",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Integra\u00E7\u00E3o Fiscal",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_INTF_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 59,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Integra\u00E7\u00E3o Fiscal",
        "Nome": "Gravar Integra\u00E7\u00E3o Fiscal",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_INTF_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 60,
        "IdMod": 3,
        "Modulo": "Configura\u00E7\u00F5es",
        "Submod": "Integra\u00E7\u00E3o Fiscal",
        "Nome": "Excluir Integra\u00E7\u00E3o Fiscal",
        "Valor": "CONFIG_TRIBUT_INTF_EXCLUI"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "Id": 67,
        "IdMod": 4,
        "Modulo": "Empresa",
        "Submod": "Lojas",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Lojas",
        "Valor": "EMPRESA_LOJAS_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 68,
        "IdMod": 4,
        "Modulo": "Empresa",
        "Submod": "Lojas",
        "Nome": "Gravar Lojas",
        "Valor": "EMPRESA_LOJAS_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 69,
        "IdMod": 4,
        "Modulo": "Empresa",
        "Submod": "Lojas",
        "Nome": "Excluir Lojas",
        "Valor": "EMPRESA_LOJAS_EXCLUI"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Id": 70,
        "IdMod": 4,
        "Modulo": "Empresa",
        "Submod": "Depositos",
        "Nome": "Visualizar Depositos",
        "Valor": "EMPRESA_DEP_LISTA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 71,
        "IdMod": 4,
        "Modulo": "Empresa",
        "Submod": "Depositos",
        "Nome": "Gravar Depositos",
        "Valor": "EMPRESA_DEP_GRAVA"
      },
      {
        "Id": 72,
        "IdMod": 4,
        "Modulo": "Empresa",
        "Submod": "Depositos",
        "Nome": "Excluir Depositos",
        "Valor": "EMPRESA_DEP_EXCLUI"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

not include key value.
How do I include the key in the generated json, as I will use it in a foreach in the frontend?
thanks!

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Also, might you please [edit] your question to include your code and JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's preferred here not to to use images for textual data, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: Please clarify *which* JSON Serializer you are using - *Newtonsoft* or *System.Text.Json* (or something else - please specify)

Comment: `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`.  `System.Text.Json` and Json.NET serialize enumerables as arrays, not objects.  For why, see [JSON serialize properties on class inheriting list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35439335/3744182) and [How do I get json.net to serialize members of a class deriving from `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21265629/3744182).  If you need a workaround, we need to see a [mcve] and know the serializer you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET serializes `"key": [ array ]` structures for collection properties (`IEnumerable`) or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it doesn't know how to otherwise serialize a class that has properties *and* enumerable elements.

You also can't use a `[JsonProperty("key")] public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }`, because you don't know the value of `"key"` at compile-time.

You could create a nasty nested dictionary from your groupings, and serialize that:

```
var queryNestedDictionaries = queryNestedGroups.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
    v => v.Values.ToDictionary(gg => gg.Key, gg => gg.Values));
```

Or create a custom converter for `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>` and write the key as property name and the value as array.